# Where did the concept of energy come from?

Tags: energy, soft-question, history

[Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy) seems to me to be a very abstract thing, and while it clearly works out very nicely, I don't understand how anyone would have thought to come up with it. Where does the concept of energy find it's roots, and how was it settled down on as a 'useful' quantity as opposed to something else?

Comment: A basic answer is that energy is a conserved quantity corresponding to a the invariance of physics laws by a time translation operation.

Comment: Related/answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy#History_of_understanding and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_energy

Comment: Aren't there others? And that surely can't be the reason it was originally used.

Comment: [Museum of the History of Science](http://www.mhs.ox.ac.uk/)

Comment: While this is apparently the way things went, isn't there some larger driving force that should have brought physicists to look for some non-physical quantity? Was it just found by guessing on things? Leibnetz got lucky with kinetic energy, but what if it was something worse-like velocity to the 15.43 power? Was there no stronger notion that pulled physicists towards energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> energy (n.)
>   1590s, "force of expression," from Middle French énergie (16c.), from Late Latin energia, from Greek energeia "activity, operation," from energos "active, working," from en "at" (see en- (2)) + ergon "work, that which is wrought; business; action" (see urge (v.)).
>
> Used by Aristotle with a sense of "force of expression;" broader meaning of "power" is first recorded in English 1660s. Scientific use is from 1807. Energy crisis first attested 1970.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=energy

---

> Huygens (1650's) was the first to develop the terminology, stating that:
>
> - energy is not like matter
> - energy does not have size, shape or occupy space
> - energy does not have inertia
>
> Instead, it was defined that energy is a measure of the ability of a physical system to perform work

http://abyss.uoregon.edu/~js/ast122/lectures/lec03.html